# Concatenating multiple rows into single line in pfam output file

Tags: python, perl, awk, sed

I have the following data in multiple lines:

```
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13499.1 EF_hand_5
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF00036.27 efhand
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13405.1 EF_hand_4
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13833.1 EF_hand_6
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13202.1 EF_hand_3
TRINITY_GG_429_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF00156.22 Pribosyltran
TRINITY_GG_431_c5_g1_i1_orf1 PF00475.13 IGPD
TRINITY_GG_461_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF01208.12 URO-D
TRINITY_GG_461_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF12876.2 Cellulase-like
```

What I want to do is to convert them into one line:

```
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13499.1 EF_hand_5 | PF00036.27 efhand | PF13405.1 EF_hand_4 | PF13833.1 EF_hand_6 | PF13202.1 EF_hand_3
TRINITY_GG_429_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF00156.22 Pribosyltran
TRINITY_GG_431_c5_g1_i1_orf1 PF00475.13 IGPD
TRINITY_GG_461_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF01208.12 URO-D | PF12876.2 Cellulase-like
```

Matching lines are always next to each other.

How could this be solved in sed/awk/Perl/Python?

Comment: Are the matching rows always on continuous lines?

Comment: Yes, I want to Concatenate the duplicated rows into a sigle line

Answer (score 0):

You could use python regex to do something like this

```
import re

out_lines = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    key = None
    key_lines = []
    for line in f:
        m = re.match(r'^(\S+)\s(.+)$', line)
        k, v = m.group(1), m.group(2)
        if k != key:
            if key:
                out_lines.append('{0} {1}'.format(key, ' | '.join(key_lines)))
            key = k
            key_lines = [v]
        else:
            key_lines.append(v)
    else:
        if key:
            out_lines.append('{0} {1}'.format(key, ' | '.join(key_lines)))

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(out_lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r ':a;N;s/^([^ ]*)( .*)\n\1(.*)$/\1\2 |\3/;ta;P;D' infile
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13499.1 EF_hand_5 | PF00036.27 efhand | PF13405.1 EF_hand_4 | PF13833.1 EF_hand_6 | PF13202.1 EF_hand_3
TRINITY_GG_429_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF00156.22 Pribosyltran
TRINITY_GG_431_c5_g1_i1_orf1 PF00475.13 IGPD
TRINITY_GG_461_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF01208.12 URO-D | PF12876.2 Cellulase-like
```

The main part is the substitution: it checks if two lines start with the same string (up to the first space), and if yes, concatenates the lines, removes the string from the second line and replaces the newline with a pipe.

Split up:

```
:label     # Label to branch to
N          # Append next line to pattern space
s/^([^ ]*)( .*)\n\1(.*)$/\1\2 |\3/  # Substitution
t label    # Branch to label if the substitution took place
P          # Strings weren't identical: print up to newline
D          # Delete up to newline, start new cycle (second line become first line)
```

To make this work with BSD sed, we have to split the command around labels and use the `-E` flag instead of `-r`:

```
sed -E -e ':a' -e 'N;s/^([^ ]*)( .*)\n\1(.*)$/\1\2 |\3/;ta' -e 'P;D' infile
```

And for good measure, a closer look at the substitution:

```
s/            # Start substitution
    ^         # Anchor at start of pattern space
    ([^ ]*)   # Match and capture non-space characters (group #1)
    ( .*)     # Capture up to end of line (group #2)
    \n        # Match newline
    \1        # Start of second line: match first capture group
    (.*)      # Capture rest of second line (group #3)
    $         # Anchor at end of pattern space
/             # Delimiter for substitution
    \1\2 |\3  # Substitute: captures groups 1 and 2, space, pipe, capture group 3
/             # End of substitution
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common programming pattern. You need to use a Perl hash to accumulate all the data belonging to each different initial field (the key). Then it is only necessary to print the hash in the order and format required

This program demonstrates. I have assumed that you want the keys printed in the lexical order of the keys. If you need anything different, such as the order they first appear in the source data, then please say so—a small change is necessary

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and sends its output to STDOUT, which may be redirected in the normal way

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %data;

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    push @{ $data{$key} }, $val;
}

print $_, ' ', join(' | ', @{ $data{$_} }), "\n" for sort keys %data;
```

#### output

```
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13499.1 EF_hand_5 | PF00036.27 efhand | PF13405.1 EF_hand_4 | PF13833.1 EF_hand_6 | PF13202.1 EF_hand_3
TRINITY_GG_429_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF00156.22 Pribosyltran
TRINITY_GG_431_c5_g1_i1_orf1 PF00475.13 IGPD
TRINITY_GG_461_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF01208.12 URO-D | PF12876.2 Cellulase-like
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build up a record of the concatenation of all the lines while the first field of the current line is the same as it was on the previous line, and then print it when the value of the first field changes:

```
$ awk '
    $1==prev { rec = rec " | " $2 " " $3 }
    $1!=prev { if (NR>1) print rec; rec=$0 }
    { prev=$1 }
    END { print rec }
' file
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13499.1 EF_hand_5 | PF00036.27 efhand | PF13405.1 EF_hand_4 | PF13833.1 EF_hand_6 | PF13202.1 EF_hand_3
TRINITY_GG_429_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF00156.22 Pribosyltran
TRINITY_GG_431_c5_g1_i1_orf1 PF00475.13 IGPD
TRINITY_GG_461_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF01208.12 URO-D | PF12876.2 Cellulase-like
```

Alternatively if your input line keys weren't contiguous and you don't care about output order being the same as input order and your input file is small enough to keep it all in memory, then you could use the hashing approach suggesting in a different answer:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1]" | "$2" "$3 : $0)} END{for (k in a) print a[k]}' file
TRINITY_GG_429_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF00156.22 Pribosyltran
TRINITY_GG_461_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF01208.12 URO-D | PF12876.2 Cellulase-like
TRINITY_GG_431_c5_g1_i1_orf1 PF00475.13 IGPD
TRINITY_GG_428_c0_g1_i1_orf1 PF13499.1 EF_hand_5 | PF00036.27 efhand | PF13405.1 EF_hand_4 | PF13833.1 EF_hand_6 | PF13202.1 EF_hand_3
```

Comment: Is it OK when I replace the **a[$1]** to **$0** like this: `awk '{a[$1]=($1 in a ? $0" | "$2" "$3 : $0)} END{for (k in a) print a[k]}' file`?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but `a[$1]=($1 in a ? $0" | "$2" "$3 : $0)` would be better written as `a[$1]=$0 ($1 in a ? " | "$2" "$3 : "")` so you're only stating the common part, $0, once and making it explicit that it happens unconditionally.